# Add just a </div> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm going crazy! :)
I need a way to add a closing `</div>` before another element. But everything I try the `</div>` gets filtered out. The problem is, that this might be the only solution for me.

So please, please have a look to this and maybe you're able to  give me a hint:

I'm building a bootstrap based template for LimeSurvey, a online survey tool. Their templates are completely done with tables and I try to find another way and to get it mobile friendly.

The template is separated into different files. For my issue this is:

```
-> Startpage
-> Navigator
-> Endpage
```

Normally it loads always a "Surveypage" between Startpage and Navigator. But there is an option which automatically puts all question directly under the startpage and therefore into my header. So in this case I need another '' or another way to close the header first.

So there's a

```
<div class="jumbotron">
```

and I have to close it before the element

```
<table id="ls-table" ... >
```

I already tried many JavaScript examples I've been able to find around the web. But none makes the job.

Thanks a lot!

Philipp

Comment: This seems like a stupid question but... Why can't you just create the `<div>` properly in the first place?

Comment: Do you not have access to the HTML code? Why are you trying to close the tag using Javascript?

Comment: Seems like an X and Y problem.

Comment: In JavaScript, you work with a DOM, not with HTML markup. The DOM has no concept of inserting a closing tag.

Comment: *"The problem is, that this will be the only solution for me."* Oh really... how do you know that?

Comment: Your issue is twofold: a closing *div* tag is **required** and browsers are very tolerant of invalid HTML. So if a required closing tag is missing, browsers will try to insert it where they think it should go.

Comment: Opening and closing tags are only relevant in the HTML source code. The HTML is parsed into DOM and that's what you are working with in JavaScript, DOM elements. At this point, the browser already tried the best it could to interpret the HTML.

Comment: Haha.. OK! I tried to clarify my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are only two ways to manipulate a web page using JavaScript.

1. The DOM, or document object model.
2. Via string-manipulation of the HTML.

Most web browsers will **NOT** allow you to do #2 directly on an already-loaded or loading document.  At best, you could find a situation wherein you read the HTML of a `<body>` and then re-parse it.  But doing so is an amazing amount of work for very little effort.

Look into the `insertBefore` method on the DOM, which will let you grab that `<table id="ls_table" >` element and move it from within that `<div>` to being a child of said `<div>`'s parent, immediately after the offending element.

Comment: `Most web browsers will NOT allow you to do #2 `. innerHTML does exactly that.